# How to update value after Ajax call synchroniously

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, express

I'm fetching data from my node(express) backend server to react front end. But when I try to access the array index values I get the output as undefined. I sure am doing something wrong here. Appreciate if someone could help me.

Here's my server side code:

```
const companyDetails = [];

companies.forEach((company) => {
    companyDetails.push(company);  
});

app.get("/api/companies", (req, res) => {
    res.json(companyDetails)
});
```

Here's my client side code:

```
let arr = [];

    function fetchComNames() {
        axios.get('/api/companies').then(res => {
          for(let i=0; i<=4; i++) {
              arr.push(res.data[i].name)
          }
        })
    }

    fetchComNames();

    console.log(arr[0]);   //undefined
```

But when I `console.log(arr);` it prints out the array. I just cant access each index value separately.

[image: Here's the out put off the "arr" when I don't specify the index]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(async () => {
    const arr = [];

    // Marking this function as async function so that 
    // we can use await to wait until result returning 
    // before further executing code below
    async function fetchComNames() {
        // I don't have access to you API
        // I resolve data after 1 second to simulate Ajax call here
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                resolve({
                    data: [{
                        name: "1"
                    }, {
                        name: "2"
                    }, {
                        name: "3"
                    }, {
                        name: "4"
                    }]
                });
            }, 1000);
        }).then(res => {
            return res.data.map(each => each.name)
        });
    }

    // You are calling Ajax call via Axios, which is a Promise. 
    // It is executed asyncrhoniously. 
    // If you need to use result from this call, 
    // you need to wait until result returning from async call. 
    // You can achieve it with await.
    
    // Update existing array
    arr.push(...(await fetchComNames()));

    // After await, arr should contain result you expected.
    console.log(arr[0]);

    // There reason why your version is not working 
    // is because you are accessing the first cell of arr 
    // wihich is still empty as the Axios is still running 
    // and you are not waiting until it returns result.
})();
```

Comment: Thanks very mush for the explanation. But I need to access this array's values out of this function. I can't seem to do that out side of this function. Is there any way I could do this ?

Comment: Please give me more code. If all you need is to add more items into an existing array it is not a problem, I will update my code

Comment: This solves my problem, Thanks very much, you helped a ton!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `axios` call is an `async` call and the follow of your code is `sync` so when you execute this code `javascript` execute the `sync` code first then the `async` one so in this case the line of code `onsole.log(arr[0]);`
is executed before the response comes from the server

Answer (score 0):

Adding to below answer, `fetchComNames` is asynchronously updated the `arr` as you're using API call. You're accessing the data before it has been updated, that's why getting `undefined`.

You can try this.

```
    
const fetchComNames = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('/api/companies')
      const array = response.data.map(c => c.name)
      OR
      const array = []
      for (let i = 0; i<= 4; i++) {
        array.push(response.data[i].name)
      }
      console.log(array[0])
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
}

fetchComNames()
```

Answer (score 0):

API calls are asynchronous so you are accessing the array before it has its values in it. Try marking your enclosing function as async and awaiting the axios get so that the call is forced to synchronous.

```js
let arr = [];

    async function fetchComNames() {
      const fetched = await axios.get('/api/companies');
          for(let i=0; i<=4; i++) {
              arr.push(fetched.data[i].name)
          }
        
    }

    fetchComNames();

    console.log(arr[0])
```

Comment: Still, this will gives `undefined`